# Spring Integration. Gateway reply error on outbound exception

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have the next configuration:

Inbound

```
<int:gateway id="inGateway" service-interface="XXX"  
    error-channel="errorChannel" 
    default-request-channel="requestChannel" 
    default-reply-channel="replyChannel" />
```

Outbound:

```
<ws:outbound-gateway id="ws-outbound-gateway"
request-channel="inbound" reply-channel="outbound"      uri="XXX" />
```

Chain 1:

```
<int:chain input-channel="requestChannel" output-channel="inbound">
XXX </int:chain>
```

Chain 2:

```
<int:chain input-channel="outbound" output-channel="replyChannel"> XXX
</int:chain>
```

Error:

```
<int:chain input-channel="errorChannel" output-channel="replyChannel">

        <int:transformer ref="logicTransformers" method="errorTransformerMethod"></int:transformer>


    </int:chain>
</beans>
```

Java Transformer:

```
final GenericError errorCatalog = errorCatalog(errorMessage);
LOGGER.warn("Transformed error from catalog: {}", errorCatalog);
final MessageBuilder<Document> builder =
MessageBuilder.withPayload(XmlUtil.parseToDocument(errorCatalog)).copyHeaders(errorMessage.getHeaders()).copyHeadersIfAbsent(errorMessage.getHeaders());
```

When the webservice of outbound is down the error go into errorChannel transformer but to reponse we have the next error:

> o.s.m.c.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel#242  Reply
>   message received but the receiving thread has exited due to an
>   exception while sending the request message:GenericMessage
>   [payload=[#document: null], headers={spanTraceId=8bf90ea9ff4266c8,
>   spanId=598680bae5f913d5, spanParentSpanId=8bf90ea9ff4266c8,
>   replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@76c751de,
>   functionalId=PRUEBASOA12,
>   errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@76c751de,
>   messageSent=true, id=2108386f-99db-98b9-3d30-3bcf45335424,
>   spanSampled=1, spanName=message:requestChannel}]

We don't understand... because we have the same flow with

Comment: Your question is incomplete. You also need to show complete configuration; instead of `XXX` in the chains; you also need to show your service interface. That error implies there is a timeout on the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

In case of error on the service level the original message is wrapped to the `MessagingException` and the `ErrorMessage` with that `payload`  is sent to the `errorChannel`. Even if you use `replyChannel` explicitly, you still have to ensure the `replyChannel` header, which is populated by the inbound gateway. And exactly this header plays the main role in the request-reply behavior in that gateway.

That `replyHeader` is still present in your error flow, but it is already a part of the `failedMessage` in the `MessagingException` payload.

So, your `logicTransformers.errorTransformerMethod` should extract that `replyChannel` header for the real reply from this method to be sent to the explicit `replyChannel`. Or you can omit this `replyChannel` at all because any way the real `sendAndReceive` is based on the `replyChannel` header.

Please, read more info in the Reference Manual:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler